# Array de dados para controller

Tags: codeigniter

boa noite

Meu controller(1) recebe os dados via input post dos campos de um formulário e joga-os dentro de um array. Posteriormente os dados são enviados para uma view (template de e-mail) a qual não vai ser renderizada.

O meu outro controller(2) é o responsável por disparar os e-mails com aqueles dados que estão no outro controller, e não sei como fazer isso sem gravar os dados no BD (nao quero gravar no db)

Não sei se fui mais claro.
Sou iniciante...obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Como não sei qual tecnologia você está utilziando, vou lhe dar três soluções:

1. Quando o controller(1) salvar os dados, os coloque na sessão para que o controller(2) os recupere o os utilize para mandar email.
2. Quando o controller(1) salvar os dados, os coloque em hidden-fields da próxima página a ser mostrada. Assim, quando o controller(2) for chamado, ele recupera os valores desses hidden-fields.
3. Quando o controller(1) salvar os dados, os coloque em cookies que ficam armazenados no navegador. O controller(2) pode então recuperar esses valores e enviá-los por email.

Contudo, caso esses dados devam ser enviados após algumas algumas interações com o usuário, eu recomendo fortemente que você os salve no banco de dados pois qualquer outra solução seria não-trivial, exceto os casos em que você salve os dados na sessão ou em cookies.

Note que salvar salvar dados na sessão não é muito recomendado, a não ser por elementos essenciais, pois isso pode onerar muito a memória do servidor de aplicações.

Cookies guardam informções referentes a perfils de usuários, logo, salvar esses dados em cookies talvez não seja a maneira mais apropriada de lidar com esses valores.

Eu particularmente gosto da idéia de salvar essas informações em banco de dados, ou caso os mesmos sejam salvos na próxima interação com o usuário, salvá-los em hidden-fields.